# Flutter app can't build for iOS after including pusher_websocket_flutter dependency

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, pusher, pusherswift

After I've read a post on how to work with Pusher, I've decided to include it in my project by adding it to my `pubspec.yamal` file. Plugin I want to ilcude is `pusher_websocket_flutter` version 0.0.2 like in the [tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-pusher-in-flutter-b4de781a0fa2).

This is not about following tutorial and implementing code, I am not even there yet. This issue is related only to integrating library into Flutter, and running the app on the iOS simulator. It doesn't even compile, and if you want you can reproduce the same issue just by adding the plugin to your app.

Approach to fixing a problem:

1. First I've specified iOS version in podfile `platform :ios, '9.0'`
2. Next is to add `ENV['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'` to specify swift version because this plugin also doesn't work without this

Even with these steps I am not able to compile and this is the error I get:

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    === BUILD TARGET firebase_analytics OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/aleksandarlugonja/Desktop/FlutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pusher_websocket_flutter-0.0.7/ios/Classes/PusherPlugin.m:4:17: error: definition of 'PusherPlugin' must be imported from module 'pusher_websocket_flutter.PusherPlugin' before it is required
    @implementation PusherPlugin
                    ^
    In module 'pusher_websocket_flutter' imported from /Users/aleksandarlugonja/Desktop/FlutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pusher_websocket_flutter-0.0.7/ios/Classes/PusherPlugin.m:2:
    /Users/aleksandarlugonja/Desktop/development/MyApp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/pusher_websocket_flutter/pusher_websocket_flutter.framework/Headers/PusherPlugin.h:3:12: note: previous definition is here
    @interface PusherPlugin : NSObject<FlutterPlugin>
```

Comment: try running `pod repo update` then rebuild the project

Comment: Nope, same error exists after I run this command.

Comment: Probably best to ask the developer https://github.com/HomeXLabs/pusher-websocket-flutter/issues